# How do file upload for Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax which has some images The following code returns an object (in `console.form`), "`FormData`", however how do I use it and or retrieve it, and whether it is right.

```
$("#form_galeria").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = 'salvarGaleria.do';

    var form;
    form = new FormData();

    form.append('fileUpload', e.target.files);
    console.log(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#form_galeria").serialize(),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err.status + ' - ' + err.statusText);
        }
    });

    $('#multiplas').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ajax `data` option to your FormData object. You will need to add whatever field values to the FormData object as well if you wish to send those along with the file upload. Also you have to append each indvidual file you cannot just append the `e.target.files` collection

```
for(var i=0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
    form.append("fileUpload[]",e.target.files[i]);
}
//or if you are only doing a single file
//form.append("fileUpload",e.target.files[0]);

form.append("someField",jQuery("#someField").val());
form.append("someOtherField",jQuery("#someOtherField").val());

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err.status + ' - ' + err.statusText);
    }
});
```